# Angular Mobile depending Service

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to ask if its possible to load "dynamicly" parameter in the constructor?
for example i have in my app.module a Module which i am loading via environment var.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    environment.mobile ? MobileModule : []
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

in this MobileModule there is a Service which i am using for Login and stuff.
The problem is i dont want these Service in Web Environment only in Mobile. I am reusing Web Components in Mobile so i use the MobileService inside of these components.
If i start my project with web environment i get an error cause No Provider for MobileService cause i am loading it in the constructor.

```js
  constructor(
    router: Router,
    public mobileService: MobileService,
  ) {}
```

is there a way to load the Service inside the constructor dynamicly ?

really silly questions ... i was thinking to create a mobile component and a web component but only for these service which is maybe only once called is a little bit over kill i think.

if would be nice to check and then do the stuff

```
if (this.mobileService) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

For optional dependencies, you need annotating the constructor parameter with `@Optional()`.

For example:

```js
constructor(router: Router, @Optional() public mobileService: MobileService) {
  if (this.mobileService) {....}
}
```

You can read more in [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#optional-dependencies).